# Cortex M-0: Simple external interrupt

Tags: embedded, arm, interrupt, microcontroller, cortex-m

I'm trying to set up an external interrupt on my LPC812 uC. I've made the following code

```
#include "LPC8xx.h"

#define RLED 7  // red LED

bool pause = false;

void PININT0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  pause = !pause;
}

int main(void) {

LPC_GPIO_PORT->DIR0 |= 1<<RLED; // set pin as output

LPC_GPIO_PORT->SET0 = 1<<RLED;

NVIC_EnableIRQ(PININT0_IRQn);

while (1)
{
    if(!pause)
    {
          LPC_GPIO_PORT->CLR0 = 1<<RLED;
    }
}

}
```

But it isn't working. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see any code to load the handler address into the vector table?

Comment: @MartinJames Is it obligatory? In file cr_startup_lpc8xx.cpp there is declaration of function void PININT0_IRQHandler(void) set as alias for  IntDefaultHandler. Doesn't it mean, that when I define the function as I did, it makes it work? Or should I really load address into vector table? If so, what is proper way to do it?

Comment: Have you set up the pin interrupt clock and the GPIO clock? Assigned pins in the STARTERP0? Have a read through chapter 8 of the user manual.

Comment: @Hipolith did you set a breakpoint in your interrupt handler? When you say that "it isn't working" you have to be a bit more specific on whats happening and what is the expected behavior. Also you should add code to your infinite loop to turn the GPIO on when pause = true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with NXP MCUs.
But at least place break piont inside PININT0_IRQHandler, to understand clearly that interrupt is not generated.

Also it will be nice to clear interrupt flag inside handler.

Some peripherals need interrupt permission in peripheral registers in addition to NVIC setup.

Did you setup input pin somewhere?

Your code only initialize GPIO 7 pin as output.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This would be better as a comment, as you're asking for more information.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am aware, that I should clear flag, but this is just to find out, how to set up interrupt properly. PIN0 is input by default as far as I know